# I can no longer access all my drive in Windows 10 even though I am administrator and the owner. Why?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to ensure that most of my files can only be read by administrators. If other users want to read the file, I want them to ask administrators first.

That way, I can lend my computer to my girlfriend knowing that she won't mess up. She can read and use only folders I use.

So I go to permissions. Each drive have 4 users.

Jim-PC/Administrators, System, Everyone, Authenticated users.

I remove everyone and authenticated users.

I ami doing this from an administrator account.

Now I cannot access any files in my hard drive at all. I got

[image]

access is denied

What I want is, if access is denied only on non administrator and then I got an option to access that anyway by using administrator password.

I change owners of the drive to administrator. Still cannot access that.

What should I do to get access to that folder. Ia m the administrator after all.

One solution that doesn't work is to change the owner of the drive to the administrators. That doesn't work.

I then try to give access to my user name. This is not what I want. I want all administrators to be able to access it. It works. However, that's kind of strange. Administrators already have access. Why do I have to explicitly give access to me?

To summarize, I am able to get access by explicitly granting access to me. However, changing ownership of the drive to me doesn't work.

Why?

Comment: Windows permissions work in such a way, if you deny everyone, you have also prevented an Administrator from accessing your files.  You will have to take ownership of the files as the Administrator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Denied on a Drive where All Users list have been deleted in Security Tab](https://superuser.com/questions/167657/access-denied-on-a-drive-where-all-users-list-have-been-deleted-in-security-tab).  Once you have ownership of the files you should be able to restore the required permissions.  By default there are two usergroups (Users, Administrators).  You grant read/write permissions to Administrators and deny read/write to Users.  All Administrators should only be in the Administrator usergroup likewise everyone else would be in the User usergroup.

Comment: Hang on let me try first. I have other ways to try

Comment: By doing what you have done, you have denied all users access to the folder, which of course means any account on the machine is specifically denied access to the folder. [Windows 10 Permissions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2623670/access-denied-or-other-errors-when-you-access-or-work-with-files-and-f)

Comment: But I am the administrator. The administrator still have permissions. Why I cannot access it?

Comment: I already explained the reason you cannot access the folder.  You explicitly denied all users access to the folder.  Deny permissions overrule allow permissions.

Comment: I do not deny permissions. I remove permissions.

Comment: I can access the drive by granting full control access to me. However changing ownership to me doesn't work. I wonder why

Comment: Ownership allows you to set permissions on a object EVEN IF YOU DON"T HAVE PERMISSION TO, and that's all it does - it doesn't grant access to the object.. Administrators' main special power is to take ownership of objects even if they don't have permission to, and now being owners change the permissions.

Comment: ah. I see. So the answer to that other questions don't work then. Can you turn your comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows there are two separate concepts. Permissions and Privileges.

Owners have a privileges of setting security of their owned objects even if the permissions deny it.

Administrators have a privilege of taking ownership even if the permissions deny it.

So to access something one takes ownership to be allowed to then set the permissions to allow one to access it.